# Develop TFS (2017) plugin from with configuration from TFS UI?

Tags: c#, plugins, tfs, continuous-integration

I need to develop a plugin for TFS 2017 which has to intercept all the builds that are initiated within TFS projects, collect that information and send it to a remote system for analytics.

As far from TFS documentation there is a possibility to develop the plugin:
using C# class library which uses the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server ISubscriber interface and putting the compiled dll into the Application Tier/Web Services/bin/Plugins folder.
In this way the plugin's ProcessEvent will be invoked for any build initiated in TFS and the plugins code will run as part of the TFS service.

Is it possible to create a configuration inside TFS web UI for this plugin e.g. when developing a plugin for Jenkins there is option of adding a configuration page which will contain configurations such as:

1. URL of the service that will be processing the data
2. Credentials that will be used for connected to the service

Also will it be possible to publish the plugin in the [visual studio market place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) so that TFS users will be able to download the plugin from the TFS extensions page?

Comment: Why are the existing build service hooks insufficient for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no on all counts.

- Server-side plugins don't have any capability to expose a UI anywhere.
- The marketplace is for extensions, not server-side plugins. Extensions are written in JavaScript and have a totally separate API.

Your best bet for what you want to do is to create a [service hook](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks) that fires when builds complete, and write a service that collects that data.

Comment: Daniel thanks for the advice!
I have been looking at the extentions tutorial of TFS with typescript (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node) The problem I have met with this, is that the extentions are configured per project wich is not my scenerio, My goal is to create a plugin which will be effective for any project (new or old) which is created within the TFS with single point configuration.
In case of using extetions (or web hooks) The question is ; is it possible to create such extention that will be configure once per TFS instance?

Comment: @Michael Cannot achieve that. Service hooks is in project level, you need to set for each project. Extension is in Collection level, it applies to the projects within the specific collection which installed the extension.